# Trigger service consumer for daily tasks - Architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices

I'm building an applications that has the capability to review the app products. The reviews traffic is high and we decided to make a separate service for review tasks. Like calculating the average of ratings for each product.

We need to calculate the review at end of each day not after each review is added to reduce amount of database updates. We decided to use a message broker solution for that task to avoid searching in the database.

What is the best message broker option for our needs? Also, is that the best solution or there is already a best practice for such needs?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for message-passing, if you want to manage it yourself. Otherwise, if you want to keep it simple, a cloud-hosted option (like [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)) is a good fit for such use-cases.

If I understand your use-case correctly, you want to accumulate the reviews in the message queues across the day, and at the end of the day you want to run one job which consumes the messages and updates the results in the DB.

If there is a huge number of messages, the memory/disk of the RabbitMQ server can get full, or the job which does the calculation at the end of the day may take too long.

Another option that you may consider, would be to store the reviews in the DB, using an index optimized for range queries, like [there is in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html), in order to grab the data for 1 day very fast, and then run the job based on that.

Also, you may consider a more granular approach, where your service calculates the reviews more frequently than once a day (maybe once a few hours). This will decrease the amount of DB operations, but it will also spread the load for that job across the day.